# Linq list any as conditional variables inside linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

```
var log = db.ViewLogs.Where(d => 
    time_ranges.Any(t => (d.FinishedWatchingAt > t.start) && (d.StartedWatchingAt < t.end))).ToList();
```

here time_ranges(which is a a helper class, not connected to database) is a list of objects from below class

```
public class TimeRange
{
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
}
```

the error I am getting:

> The LINQ expression 't => EntityShaperExpression:
> Bscl.Models.ViewLog
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> .FinishedWatchingAt > t.start && EntityShaperExpression:
> Bscl.Models.ViewLog
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> .StartedWatchingAt < t.end && __userIds_1.Contains(EntityShaperExpression:
> Bscl.Models.ViewLog
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> .UserId)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

But I can't establish it. please forgive me if its a dumb mistake and help me.

Comment: Please show your error and your example and expected

Comment: the issue is that you are using Linq to Entities, so you cannot use `Any()` within `Where()`. Can you provide more details on you code? What is time_range and where it comes from?

Comment: edited the question for you. please check

Comment: How many items in `time_ranges`? If it is more than 100, you need to use third party extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is due to Entity Framework's inability to translate some LINQ operations into SQL queries. Specifically, your problem lies in the usage of the Any operator with a list of complex objects (time_ranges), which is not directly convertible to SQL. The database provider doesn't know how to execute this part of the query on the database server.

One way to solve this problem is by rewriting your query to be understandable by Entity Framework, or performing part of the operations in memory (client-side) by loading the data into memory first. Note that this could be inefficient for large datasets.

Try this instead :

```
var log = new List<ViewLog>();

foreach (var range in time_ranges)
{
    var temp = db.ViewLogs
                 .Where(d => d.FinishedWatchingAt > range.start && d.StartedWatchingAt < range.end)
                 .ToList();

    log.AddRange(temp);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is the thing I want to overcome as ranges are in length of atleast 50k. your reply enriched my knowledge so thanks.

Comment: This answer looks like it was written at least in part with the help from some AI generator like ChatGPT. Do please be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: So I guess that writting sensfull response is now being consider as AI generated? Good to know.

Comment: @WiktorKot used chatgpt myself for solution results were nowhere near this, I trust you bruv, don't worry about this weak bot. have a nice day